# Content within types.h — where does the compiler define the width of int, signed int and others?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, clang

I read both `/usr/include/bits/types.h` and `/usr/include/sys/types.h`, but only see them use "unsigned int" or "signed int" to define some other relatively rarely used type for us, e.g:

```
typedef signed char __int8_t;
...
typedef signed int __int32_t;
```

or:

```
#define __S32_TYPE              int
#define __U32_TYPE              unsigned int;
```

As to "where is the `signed int` (or `int`) originally defined?" and "in which file, gcc decide the `int` should be 4 bytes width in my x86-64 server"?  I cannot find anything.

I am wondering the process in which the gcc/g++ compiler define these primitive type for us, and want to see the originally definition file.
Please tell me the originally position or enlighten me about some method to find them.

Comment: Primitive types are not defined in a header file. They are built-in types.

Comment: The original definition files are part of the gcc source ... there are different definition files for different architectures.

Comment: typedef unsigned char __u_char;
typedef unsigned short int __u_short;
typedef unsigned int __u_int;
typedef unsigned long int __u_long;  they difine alias for short,char,signd int here .but int,long int ,short int ....,they are built in,and is nowhere to find them in our /user/include ?tks

Comment: What does that comment mean or what is its purpose? If you want to clarify your question, you should edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic types are intrinsic to the compiler; they are built in when the compiler is compiled, and are not defined anywhere you can find it easily.  (Somewhere in the code there is the relevant information, but it won't be particularly easy to find.)

Thus, you won't find the information in a header directly. You can get the size information from the `sizeof()` operator.  You can infer sizes from the macros in `<limits.h>` and `<float.h>`.

Comment: ,so there is no reliable way to guarrantee that some type occupy the same width across different os/hadware platform, but with the exception ,intXX_t is almostly the same size across platform,and we can see this as a contract.am i right?

Comment: There is one reliable way — the types defined in `<stdint.h>` such as `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, etc.  They are not always defined; if a platform has no 8-bit type, it will not define `uint8_t` (but it will define `uint_least8_t`).

Comment: tks. and this is one of the functions of <stdint.h>,and <stdint.h>is from the language but not from the compiler or os,to make some basic portalbility across platforms.--------please correctify me!

Comment: `<stdint.h>` is a part of the C99 standard, but was not in C89/C90. If you port to systems with archaic compilers (e.g. Windows with Microsoft C89 compilers — they have not yet reached C99, let alone the current C11 standard), then you will have to provide your own surrogate header — but it is easily done and there are examples available; you probably find them on SO and certainly via Google searching.

Comment: i am shamed to ask:why stdint.h does not tell people  of it's own function. By reading through the stdint.h,i really cannot see the greate meaning of typenames like "intXX_t "

Comment: Read what the standard says about them. It is pretty striaght-forward — that section is one of the simpler ones to understand.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler."stdint.h is different for different compilers on different platforms, that is the way. On some other platform/compiler where int is only 16bits, stdint.h might define something like typedef long int32_t or even do that conditionally."----so,stdint.h is tailored for different enviroments,it's content is not all the same ,though it comes from the c standard?

Comment: Yes; the detailed contents of `<stdint.h>` varies from platform to platform; it may even vary on a single machine depending on whether the compilation is for 32-bit or 64-bit, for example. However, the 'output' from `<stdint.h>` is a known set of `typedef` names (`uint8_t` etc), with implementation-defined values (`unsigned char` or plain `char`, for example).

Answer (score 1):

`int`, `unsigned int`, `long` and some others are system type, they are defined by compiler itself. Compiler has some demands on those type, for instance `int` must be at least 16 bits, but compiler may make it longer. Usually `int` means *most efficient integral type of at least 16 bits*.

You should not rely on actual size of int, if you need it to hold more than 32767, please stick to `long` or `long long` type. If you need certain amount of bits integral due to desired overflow behavior, you can use `uint16_t`/`uint32_t` types. If you want to make sure there is at least certain amount of bits, you can also use `uint_fast16_t`/`uint_fast32_t`.

Comment: tks to nyrl. where is uint16_t/uint32_t defined ?i can only see typedef unsigned int u_int32_t and it is an alias of unsigned int too.i want a type of 4 bytes width  to store something regadless of the compiler ,regadless of the os and cpu

Comment: @user624866 In `stdint.h`. You might also want to include `inttypes.h` for `printf()`/`scanf()` format specifiers for those types. Want 4 bytes? Use `int32_t`/`uint32_t`, it will be exactly 4 bytes with some guarantees on overflow behavior.

Comment: The standard makes demands of the compiler; the compiler might (or might not) implement to meet those demands. However, that's nit-picking.

Comment: i get the uint_fast16_t/uint_fast32_t here./usr/include/stdint.h:typedef unsigned int              uint_fast32_t; it's an alias for unsigned int too,so it's width is not constant regardless of different os/compiler

Comment: @user624866 Note that `uint_fast32_t` is usually not *faster* than `uint32_t`. While later is always 32bits, the former allowed to be larger if that is beneficial.

Comment: to nyrl,"Want 4 bytes? Use int32_t/uint32_t, it will be exactly 4 bytes with some guarantees on overflow behavior.".sorry,may be i mislead you,let's do not stick to any spicific type. is there a mechanism for my code to use a constant wide type across any os/hadware?

Comment: @user624866 yes, use `uintXX_t` types, it is most portable if you deal with modern compilers. If compiler supports it, it will be XX bits long.

Comment: @nyrl,tks,really."typedef int                     int32_t",this is how int32_t difined,it syas the size of int32_t is determined by int and "int" is variable at length,en..,if so,how can size of intXX_t will be promised to be the same ?

Comment: @user624866 `stdint.h` is different for different compilers on different platforms, that is the way. On some other platform/compiler where int is only 16bits, `stdint.h` might define something like `typedef long int32_t` or even do that conditionally. But int is *usually* 32 bits for most popular platforms, so you are likely to see that `int32_t` is an alias for `int`, just **don't rely** on that.

Comment: @nyrl,i get some hint from you."You should not rely on actual size of int, if you need it..... If you need certain amount of bits integral due to desired overflow behavior, you can use uint16_t/uint32_t types. If you want to make sure there is at least certain amount of bits, you can also use uint_fast16_t/uint_fast32_t."--when i read the types.h and stdint.h,i can not infer those rule out of these header files,would you please tell me how to find the rationale from some doucumentation? for me ,the method is better than the result,please let me be smarter,tks again!

Comment: @user624866 Always lookup standard when in doubt :) ISO C99, ch 7.18.1.1: *The typedef name uintN_t designates an unsigned integer type with width N. Thus,
uint24_t denotes an unsigned integer type with a width of exactly 24 bits.*

Comment: @nyrl. and this is the rule exerted by c language standard,it requires different compiler fullfill "uint24_t denotes an unsigned integer type with a width of exactly 24 bits"  ----i am not certain

Comment: @user624866 uintN_t types are **optional**, specifically: *These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with
widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a
two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.* So, if there is uint24_t, then its meaning is defined as I quoted above.